# MVVM-C: why connecting Coordinator to ViewModel instead of View?

Tags: mvvm, architecture

I read a lot of blog posts about MVVM-C (Swift, especially), and always a navigation is triggered View => ViewModel => Coordinator.

Wouldn‘t it be easier to have a reference between View(Controller) and Coordinator to avoid the intermediate step with the ViewModel? What‘s the reason the View(Controller) must not know about the Coordinator?

Answer (score 0):

I agree with above [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59284576/751641), but would like to add some more reasoning:

Following `Single responsibility` from `SOLID`, `ViewController` which is `View` in `MVVM` should not be responsible for screen transitions and notifying of `Coordinator` that a transition should occur.

Screen transition is a part of business logic. So it can be triggered in `ViewModel` and that is a good place for it.

Comment: Your answer is very subjective, because it can be argued that screen transition is not part of business logic, but application logic.
https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/293885/what-is-the-difference-between-business-and-application-logic
Also it can be argued that business logic belongs to the Model, not the ViewModel.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37671866/should-i-implement-business-logic-on-a-model-or-a-viewmodel